# c# how to let web browser automatically load a url

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to load a web viewer that automatically, as the program starts, loads a url.

I've tried:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
```

some code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");

        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when the brogram runs, that the web viewer automatically goes to a url.

Comment: Did you try to move Navigate() call up to the `Form1_Load` ?

Comment: it says form1 is a method and cannot be applied to this context @DK.

Comment: please show the exact code you tried with `Form1_Load`  that throws the error as an edit to your question.

Comment: I tried:         ```        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Form1_Load.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");

        } ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code inside `Form1_Load`

```
// for initial loading of the page this doesn't have to be true, this is only for navigation after loading the 1st page
webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true; 

webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new 
          WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
```

Comment: I've tried to put it in between the     ```private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}```
and got an error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!